# Check which files run on request

Tags: php, debugging

As the application I work on is growing I would like to track if files are included when it's not needed at all. Therefore I would like to log which files are called/included/required when a page is loaded.

As an example:

When using a template system, the class is including the model and the model is including the template file. So, three files are used to get the output.

I found the following function:

```
debug_backtrace();
```

But this only gives back the function and filename where it's placed.

Anyone a solution, or how do you keep track of the large number of files used in the applications you build?

**UPDATE**

I've tried the following in my class:

```
function __destruct() {

    $included_files = get_included_files();

    foreach ($included_files as $filename) {
        echo "$filename\n";
    }

}
```

This gives back all the includes that happened within the class, BUT it's skipping includes within the included files. So the template models are loaded, but it doesn't show the template file names as an example.

Comment: Nowadays, large applications often make use of [class autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) to alleviate this problem. In particular, Composer is really good at managing class includes as well as function library includes https://getcomposer.org/

Comment: The long and short of it is: the autoloader knows were to look to find files, based on naming conventions (such as namespacing) and will load them automatically for classes & functions not currently loaded. You then don't usually call `include/require` yourself.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelBerkowski it's def something I'm going to use in my other projects!